# Kafka connect to HBase

Tags: apache-kafka, hbase, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to to use Kafka Connect to HBase and there are no Confluent supported connectors available for HBase, though there are some community connectors available. We are not really ready to take risk in production with out support to the connectors: Is there any other work around for HBase connectivity from Kafka Connect? Can we use Kafka JDBC connector for Kafka Connect?

Comment: Do you have support for Phoenix if Kafka Connect JDBC breaks your HBase tables?

Comment: No we don't have Phoenix in our system,but is it mandatory to have Phoenix for using jdbc connectors to hbase?

Comment: Hbase uses Thrift, not JDBC without it, so yes